# JConsole didn't show the mbean attributes and methods that I defined in the mbean

Tags: java, spring, jmx, jconsole, spring-jmx

I'm trying to register mbeans by spring annotation. The beans were showing correctly in the jconsole but the attributes and methods defined in the class didn't show up. What's wrong with it?

here's one mbean for example:

```
@ManagedResource(objectName="com.xormedia.aqua.mbean:name=AuthenticationServer",description="AuthenticationServerSummary")
public class AuthenticationServerSummaryMbean implements MonitorMXBean {
private String ip;
private String port;

@ManagedAttribute
public String getIp() {
    return ip;
}
public void setIp(String ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
}

@ManagedOperation(description="show port number")
public String getPort() {
    return port;
}
public void setPort(String port) {
    this.port = port;
}
}
```

I followed the guides online, configuring the spring xml but there are only mbeans without any tree structure for the attributes and methods.

Just like this.[image: Mbean without attributes and methods]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your approach into the following:

Add `<context:mbean-export/>` in your spring config.

Change your class a bit:

```
@ManagedResource(
        objectName = "com.xormedia.aqua.mbean:name=AuthenticationServer",
        description = "AuthenticationServerSummary",
        log = true,
        logFile = "jmx.log",
        currencyTimeLimit = 1)
public class AuthenticationServerSummaryMbean {
    private String ip;
    private String port;

    @ManagedAttribute(description = "IP Address", currencyTimeLimit = 1)
    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    @ManagedAttribute(description = "Port number", currencyTimeLimit = 1)
    public String getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(String port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
}
```

Register your mBean:

```
<bean id="mBeanService" class="yourpackage.AuthenticationServerSummaryMbean"/>
```

Comment: I tried... but it still failed.. I can't invoke `getIp()` and `getPort()` in the jconsole GUI. No method was shown.

Comment: What version of Spring is it? can you try to define `org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter` explicitly instead of `<context:mbean-export/>`?

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging, the `MBeanExporter` spits out lots of useful information as it registers MBeans.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis It's **spring version 3.1.2**. Previously, I configured it with `org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter` and `org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource` and `org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler` and `org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.MetadataNamingStrategy` . These three beans worked the same as `<context:mbean-export/>`.

Comment: @GaryRussell ahh.. I see. but how to turn on debug logging for the `Mbeanexporter`?

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis I just fixed the problem. It's because I   `implements MonitorMXBean` interface. I removed the interface to make it as a standard mbean and self-naming interface,which I got from another question in stackoverflow. Although not really understand why it just worked fine without that interface. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Consult the documentation for your logging subsystem, for example log4j; the `MBeanExporter` is in package `org.springframework.jmx.export`.